# Subtract values of ranged cells from a cell if ranged cells are not blank

Tags: excel

First, my apologies for the confusion of this question. The title probably isn't worded very well, but I couldn't think of a better way to ask it. And because I don't know how to ask it simply, I could not find any answers.

I am wondering if there is a way to subtract a value of a cell from another cell if yet another cell is not blank. This is simply done when not using a range using something like:

```
=if(a1<>"", c1-b1, c1)
```

But I want to check multiple cells in a range. If a cell in that range is not blank, subtract a correlated value from a working total, otherwise subtract nothing. Go to next cell in the range, if that cell is not blank, subtract a correlated value, and so on...

Let's say:

- Original value to be subtracted from is c1
- Range of cells to be checked are a1:a10
- Coorelated value to subtract is located in b1:b10

So... in a1:a10, there will be date. If a1 is not blank, subtract b1 from c1. Lets call this value workingValue. Go to a2... if a2 is not blank, subtract b2 from workingValue. Go to a3... if a3 is not blank, subtract b3 from workingvalue, and on down the list.

The final workingValue can go anywhere, but for simplicity, let's put it in C2.

Is this possible with an excel formula (not VB)?

Comment: Where do you want the output?  Do you want it line by line or a sum of the differences?

Comment: It can go anywhere really... but for simplicity, let's say C2.

Comment: Is it line by line or total?

Comment: I suppose, in the end, it wouldn't really matter. I was originally thinking line by line to ensure no values are skipped. But your comment does give me an idea... you might be on the same track. Perhaps add up the totals based on blank cells, making this my working value, and then subtract my workingValue from C1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in C2:

```
=(C1*ROWS(A1:A10))-SUMIF(A1:A10,"<>",B1:B10)
```

Comment: This works perfectly if I remove the *ROWS segment. (=(C1)-SUMIF(A1:A10,"<>",B1:B10)). The question was a little hard to word, so naturally it was probably a little hard to understand. But you nailed it. Thank you!!!